# Do I need to install Hive if all I want is to use HCatalog with Pig and MR?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

Want to use HDP2.2 distribution, but plan to only use Pig+MR for my ETL jobs. Would like to document schemas with HCatalog, but would like to avoid having to setup Hive. Do I need it for having HCatalog ?

Answer (score 1):

Since HCatalog is a part if Hive, yes you need to install Hive in order to be able to use HCatalog. (see https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.0.0/api/hcatalog/core/index.html for reference)